# Событие перетаскивания для slider в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть простой `slider`. Есть у него событие `ValueChanged`. Оно срабатывает, когда значение `value` меняется и не важно, меняется оно программно либо из интерфейса. Мне нужно, чтобы событие вызывалось, когда пользователь перетащил мышкой ползунок и отпустил кнопку мыши (надеюсь такое есть) + знать какое значение `value` он установил, как в `ValueChanged` есть `e.NewValue`. В крайнем случае отследить когда `ValueChanged` меняется программно, а когда пользователем.

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не выставить флаг на то время, пока вы меняете значение программно?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду поставить значение переменной и проверять?

Comment: Ну что-то типа `isChangingMyself = true; Value = 20; isChangingMyself = false;`. А в обработчике `ValueChanged` `if (isChangingMyself) ...`.

Comment: Да, способ рабочий. Интересно, может за нас уже подумали и есть событие как раз под эти нужды

Comment: Ну, я всегда так делал. Возможно, можно посмотреть на sender или originalSender в событии, но я не уверен.